# Capistrano Deployment: a Task before `deploy:finalize_update` Is not Executed

Tags: deployment, capistrano, task

I'm using Capistrano v2.13.4 for deployment.

A Capistrano task (`deploy:special_treats`) before `deploy:finalize_update` is not executed.

The task `deploy:special_treats` does some preparation (setup the internet access) for `bundle:install`, otherwise, `bundle:install` will not be able to reach the Internet (`[out :: servername] Could not reach https://rubygems.org/`

In `config/deploy.rb`

`before 'deploy:finalize_update', 'deploy:special_treats'`

and

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :special_treats do
    run "echo 'something special treats: setup the Internet access'"
  end
end
```

The result for `cap deploy:update`

```
$ cap deploy:update
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "svn info https://svnlinks --username username --password password --no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
    command finished in 10336ms
  * getting (via export) revision 33268 to /tmp/20120927171608
    executing locally: svn export -q --username username --password password --no-auth-cache  -r33268 https://svnlinks /tmp/20120927171608
    command finished in 79314ms
  * processing exclusions...
  * Compressing /tmp/20120927171608 to /tmp/20120927171608.tar.gz
    executing locally: tar czf 20120927171608.tar.gz 20120927171608
    command finished in 1401ms
    servers: ["servername"]
 ** sftp upload /tmp/20120927171608.tar.gz -> /tmp/20120927171608.tar.gz
    [servername] /tmp/20120927171608.tar.gz
    [servername] done
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "cd /usr/website/rr/releases && tar xzf /tmp/20120927171608.tar.gz && rm /tmp/20120927171608.tar.gz"
    servers: ["servername"]
    [servername] executing command
    command finished in 774ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /usr/website/rr/releases/20120927171608 && bundle install --gemfile /usr/website/rr/releases/20120927171608/Gemfile --path /usr/website/rr/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development 

test"
    servers: ["servername"]
    [servername] executing command
 ** [out :: servername] Could not reach https://rubygems.org/
    command finished in 1403ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /usr/website/rr/releases/20120927171608; true"
    servers: ["servername"]
    [servername] executing command
    command finished in 344ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3-p194' -c 'cd /usr/website/rr/releases/20120927171608 && bundle install --gemfile /usr/website/rr/releases/20120927171608/Gemfile --path 

/usr/website/rr/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on servername
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue but in the `after deploy:finalize_update` trigger. The difference is that my script works in another machine for a long time.

I don't have capistrano locked as a gem in the `Gemfile`, so I tried reverting to the same version of the working machine which is `2.6.0` but that did not fix it.

After some research and several trials, I have found some issues at the github project like [this](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/256) that leads to [that](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/255) but looks like folks can't fully reproduce it.

I have then headed to the docs and browsing I found that Capistrano behaviors have been affected by recent changes on the `0.9.x` versions of rake that have to do with namespace conflicts as you can see in this brief and tiny note that can be found at the deploy:create_symlink section of [Capistrano Tasks wiki page](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks)

I did not have time to fix the script to work with latest versions of both rake and capistrano but I was able to have it back working on a different machine by reverting rake to version `0.8.7`.

I hope this can get you going and provide some clues towards the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I found a solution setting up the Internet Access.  I used `set :default_environment { 'env_var1' => 'value1', 'env_var2' => 'value2' }`, and it works.  As a matter of factor, the environment variables we try to set in a task are not persistent during the whole Capistrano deployment session.